# Php and Godaddy - Signup form not received via email

Tags: php, email, gmail, google-apps

Past long my signup form used to send me email everytime a new lead is generated from my website.

I recently changed my email service provider from Hosting email to GMAIL APPS and changed MX Records in my Godaddy account as:

```
5   @   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 600 seconds 
5   @   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 600 seconds 
10  @   ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 600 seconds 
10  @   ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 600 seconds 
1   @   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM  600 seconds
```

ever since i changed these fields I am not receiving any emails on gmail or any other CCd email.

Can you guys suggest if i needed to add any more fields?

P.S: I have removed exiting fields already because if i keep them ALL Emails sent are bounced

```
10  @   mailstore1.secureserver.net 1 Hour  
0   @   smtp.secureserver.net   1 Hour
```

Comment: And what is the explanation inside the bounced emails?

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit that could go wrong when setting up google apps for the first time.

The majority of the time updates to domain name records takes some time to propagate to other DNS servers and can take up to 48 hours to complete before other MX servers will be able to send to the new entry. Though this is usually within an hour if they were previously cached with a 1 hour TTL.

Though make sure you created `MX` records and not accidently `C-Name` or `A` records.

You'll also need to ensure you have added the Google TXT `spf` record to your DNS server, so that emails being sent from gmail are not possibly rejected.

```
Type | Name | Value                                | TTL
TXT  | @    | v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all  | 1 Hour
```

https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en

Be sure you have deleted any other conflicting SPF records and added other allowed servers to the record's value, such as your webserver's IP address.

To troubleshoot your network setup and ensure records are propagating you can use [MXToolbox Network Tools](http://mxtoolbox.com/NetworkTools.aspx).

To troubleshoot your google apps setup, in your Google Apps Control Panel ensure:

- The domain name is correctly listed and **Active** as the Primary Domain in the set Domain.
- Under Apps\Google Apps add the GMail App if it is not already
- Under Apps\Google Apps\Gmail set to `On for Everyone` if not already
- Under Apps\Google Apps\Gmail\Email addresses check the desired email addresses exist, otherwise create the new desired *Users* or *Groups*
- Under Apps\Google Apps\GMail\Advanced Settings

  - Select your organization domain from the top of the left menu list
  - At the bottom there will be a *Catch-All-Address*
  - Change from `Discard` to `Forward the email to`
  - Supply your username for the organization
  - Save the Settings
  - Test sending an email to it and a non-existent user within the domain after about 5-10 minutes from the same account.
  - Test sending emails from an external email server (such as yahoo, outloook, or ISP provided email account).

You can also follow the instructions on setting up google apps email provided by google https://support.google.com/a/answer/172171

Comment with any issues you may have.